# Build Failure on Android Studio

Tags: android, compilation, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After updating all the Google support libraries to the latest versions, from v21 to v22.2.0 and Play Services to v7.5, my project no longer builds successfully. The log i get is as follows:

```
app:preDexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}


:app:dexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar ","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 46.623 secs
```

I have tried reverting the libraries to the earlier versions but the same error still arises. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Comment: looks like you hit the dex limit https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: @Modge, the developer site advises using the multidex support library, but they give a warning if the app has a target or minimum sdk lower than 14. Is there a significant negative impact of using the said library?

Comment: please read the link above and the section "Limitations of the multidex support library". Also any app over 65k methods is going to have a larger apk size and build time than it needs

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Play services is a big library with tens of thousands of methods that will eat into your dex limit. Its better to replace the play services imports with just the parts you need. From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play service APIs into your app.

```
Google+ com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0
Google Account Login    com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.5.0
Google Actions, Base Client Library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0
Google App Indexing com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:7.5.0
Google App Invites  com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:7.5.0
Google Analytics    com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0
Google Cast com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:7.5.0
Google Cloud Messaging  com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0
Google Drive    com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:7.5.0
Google Fit  com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:7.5.0
Google Location, Activity Recognition, and Places   com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0
Google Maps com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0
Google Mobile Ads   com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0
Google Nearby   com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:7.5.0
Google Panorama Viewer  com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:7.5.0
Google Play Game services   com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:7.5.0
SafetyNet   com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:7.5.0
Google Wallet   com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:7.5.0
Android Wear    com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.5.0
```

Comment: That was it. The app builds and compiles successfully now. Thanks  a lot.

Comment: such a painful experience. I can't believe the google docs still tell you to install the whole thing... Thanks

Comment: wow, i am new to android and was completed clueless and so frustrated, thanks for this!

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this answer! I've been searching for hours now. Google should edit their docs to only include the library's that you need.